# Rock Paper Scissors function help in Python

Tags: python, function

I just started learning Python, and I am trying to write a basic Rock Paper Scissors program for my assignment. The game is intended to go on for 10 rounds, while keeping track the score between the player and the computer. I have two specific problems with it.

```
import random

def welcome_prompt():
    print ("ROCKER PAPER SCISSORS in PYTHON Assignment")        
    print ("Rules: Rocks beats Scissors, Scissors beats Paper, Paper beats Rock")

def get_player_move():
    print ('Round ' + str(round))        
    print ("Please play one of the following")
    get_player_move = raw_input(" 1) [R]ock, 2) [P]aper, 3) [S]cissors:")

    if get_player_move == ("R"):
        print ("You used Rock!") 
        return 1              

    elif get_player_move == ("P"):        
        print ("You used Paper!")
        return 2

    elif get_player_move == ("S"):
        print ("You used Scissors!")
        return 3

    else:
        print "Invalid input, please use capitalized initial (R,P,S)"
        return get_player_move()

def get_computer_move():
        get_computer_move = random.randint(1,3)

        if get_computer_move == 1:
            print ("Computer used Rock!")
        return 1

    elif get_computer_move == 2:
        print ("Computer used Paper!")
        return 2

    elif get_computer_move == 3:
        print ("Computer used Scissors!")
        return 3



def compare_moves(get_player_move, get_computer_move):
# Rock = 1
# Paper = 2
# Scissors = 3

    if (get_player_move ==  1 and get_computer_move == 1) or (get_player_move == 2 and get_computer_move == 2) or (get_player_move == 3 and get_computer_move == 3):
    print ("It's a tie!")
    return 0  

    elif (get_player_move == 1 and get_computer_move == 3) or (get_player_move == 2 and get_computer_move == 1) or (get_player_move == 3 and get_computer_move == 2):
    print ("You win the round!")
    return 1

    elif (get_player_move == 1 and get_computer_move == 2) or (get_player_move == 2 and get_computer_move == 3) or (get_player_move == 3 and get_computer_move == 1):
    print ("You lose the round!")
    return -1

    elif (get_player_move == 4):
    print ("You didn't put in correct input, computer gets a free win")
    return -1


# Game Program

player_score = 0
comp_score = 0
round = 0


welcome_prompt()

('Round ' + str(round))
while round< 10:
    round = round + 1
    get_player_move()
    get_computer_move()
    compare_moves(get_player_move, get_computer_move)

    if compare_moves == 1:
        player_score = player_score + 1
        print 'Player Score'+ str(player_score)
        print 'Computer Score'+ str(player_score)
    elif compare_moves == -1:
        comp_score = comp_score + 1
        print 'Player Score'+ str(player_score)
        print 'Computer Score'+ str(player_score)        

print "Game Over"
```

Firstly, I can't get the compare_move function to recall the returned values  from both get_player_move and get_computer_move. The game can run without any error, but it just skips the comparison/ score component completely. I am still a bit iffy with the basics, so not exactly sure what is  missing.

Secondly, in the get_player_move function, when I enter an invalid input (example: blah) to test the raw_input, it gives an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Rock Paper Scissors.py", line 85, in <module>
    get_player_move()
  File "C:\Python27\Rock Paper Scissors.py", line 32, in get_player_move
    return get_player_move()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So how do you make a function to asks for the correct raw_input again after entering invalid input, without interrupting the while loop?

Explanation is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Your `compare_moves` function seems overly complicated.  You may observe that rock-paper-scissors forms a 3 element ring; rock=0 < paper=1 < scissors=2 < rock=0.  If you compute the distance from the computer's move to the player's move modulo 3 (`dist = (computer-player)%3`), then `dist == 0` implies a tie, `dist == 1` implies the computer wins, and `dist == 2` implies the player wins.

Comment: Your `compare_moves` code is also not indented correctly.  If it were C code, I would re-inent it myself, but since this is python, doing so could change the meaning of the code, so I leave that to you.

Comment: Note that python does not support Tail Call Optimization (TCO), so `get_player_move` will eventually cause a stack-overflow (takes a drink) if the player enters enough invalid input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local variable `get_player_move` *inside* the function `get_player_move()`; you cannot then still use the function name (a global).

Rename the `get_player_move` local variable.

So, instead of:

```
get_player_move = raw_input(" 1) [R]ock, 2) [P]aper, 3) [S]cissors:")
```

use:

```
move = raw_input(" 1) [R]ock, 2) [P]aper, 3) [S]cissors:")
```

perhaps.

To get user input, it's best not to rely on recursion, however. The user could hit 'C' forever and then your program would crash with an `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. It's easier to use a loop instead:

```
while True:
    move = raw_input(" 1) [R]ock, 2) [P]aper, 3) [S]cissors:")
    if move == "R":
        print ("You used Rock!") 
        return 1              

    # etc.

    else:
        print "Invalid input, please use capitalized initial (R,P,S)"
```

Because you return from the function when a correct choice is made, the loop automatically is exited as well. If however you get to the end and `Invalid input` is printed, the `while True` loop starts at the top again and the user is asked once more to enter a choice.

Next: although your function returns a choice (an integer), you never store that return value. You must store it where you called the function:

```
player_move = get_player_move()
computer_move = get_computer_move()
result = compare_moves(player_move, computer_move)

if result == 1:
```

Note that it's not the function name that holds the return value; it's a separate variable. `player_move` is assigned whatever the `get_player_move()` returned, for example.

You can then pass these returned values to `compare_moves()`; it also returns a result, here stored in `result` for further comparisons.

Comment: The while True loop works, thank you. However, renaming the local variable in get_player_move still can't get compare_move function work tho

Comment: With the `while` loop the rename is no longer as important.

Comment: @user3424161: I see more problems indeed, addressed in my update.

Comment: Is it needed to put store data line for the both get_player_move/ get_computer_move function itself? Or only at the compare_moves function?

Comment: If you want to pass the return values of `get_player_move()` and `get_computer_move()` to the `compare_move()` function, then you need to do so, yes.

Comment: When I try to store data with player_move = get_player_move(), it works in storing a value, but it also triggers the function itself, causing a loop

Comment: @user3424161: yes, calling a function calls the function. If you don't want to call it more than once, just use the return value everywhere you need that return value.